# Since Google Apps supports unlimited groups, is it possible to use groups as a substitute for aliases?

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email, google-groups

Google Apps supports unlimited group email addresses, but only 30 email aliases per user. Does this mean that instead of creating an alias `myalias@example.com` for `michael@example.com`, I can just create a group email address `myalias@example.com` for a group that only contains `michael@example.com` and achieve the same effect?

I don't need to send email from these group email addresses (which is possible with an alias); I only need to receive email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, yes, you can use Google Groups as alias replacements. Please see the details below.

- There is no limit to the number of groups you can create. (src: ["Is there a limit to the number of groups a user can create?"](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167085?hl=en#limits) However, a given user can only be the owner of 1000 groups. If the group is created by a Super Admin or user with the Create Groups role, the group doesn't need an owner to exist.
- Size limits for incoming messages remain the same as in vanilla Gmail - 25 MB. (src: ["Is there a size limit for messages sent to a group?"](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167085?hl=en#limits))
- **Receiving limits are lower than a Gmail account** - the entire group can receive no more than 300 messages per 5 minutes or 1800 messages per hour per sender. ([src](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2524618)) This is compared to 180 messages per minute (900 messages per 5 minutes) for a Google Apps for Work Gmail account. ([src](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1366776?hl=en))
- EDIT: Also note that groups must be set so "Public" can post to them (otherwise everyone who tries to email your group will get a Delivery Status Notification (Failure) message). [image: public posting permissions]

**Bonus Benefit**

- The same method can be implemented for users on an external (non-example.com) domain - so long as the group has the "Allow members external to this organization" setting selected (hxxps://groups.google.com/a/example.com/forum/#!groupsettings/yourgroupnamehere/basic) [image]

Comment: Thank you, this is great. I'm actually looking to use Google Apps as a personal email service (using my custom domain) that will only have a single user (me), so the receiving limits don't bother me and I shouldn't be affected by the permissions limits.

Comment: If a group can have members external to the domain, that means I can set up a group (`mygroup@example.com`) that, when anyone in the group sends an email to that address, everyone in the group, whether or not they're on an external domain, receives the message and can reply to it, right?

Comment: @MichaelA, that is correct.

Comment: You event might want to look into the [Collaborative Inbox](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167430?hl=en) feature, which makes a Google Group behave more like a mailbox.