# Can Google Apps Group email addresses and aliases have plus signs and periods?

Tags: gmail

Do Google Apps group email addresses and email aliases support plus signs and arbitrary periods in addresses, like [normal Gmail addresses do](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html)?

For example, if I have a group email address (e.g. [one that I'm using as an alias](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/69048/79753)) called `mygroup@example.com`, will emails sent to `mygroup+subaddress@example.com` or `my.group@example.com` go through to the group email address?

If I have an alias `myalias@example.com`, can I use `myalias+subaddress@example.com` or `my.alias@example.com` in the same fashion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Plus signs: **Yes**.

- Groups: I just tested sending an email to `mygroup+something@example.com`, and the message came through allright.
- Aliases: Successfully tested sending an email to `myalias+something@example.com`.

Arbitrary periods: **No**.

- Groups: Test message to `my.group@example.com` is returned with a *Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently* message
- Aliases: Test message to `my.alias@example.com` does not seem to be delivered.

Comment: Just tried adding a member with a plus sign to a Google Group and it failed: `"x+banana@aaaa.bbbb.com" at position 1 invalid: These characters are not allowed: +`

Comment: @joehanna Yes, but this is about valid _group_ addresses, not addresses of group _members_.

Comment: My bad. I figured he was referring to member email addresses when he mentioned "email addresses" twice in the title and description.

Comment: @joehanna Good point, I have made an attempt at clarifying the title.

Comment: for plus signs in aliases, is this the default behavior or is it something that must be enabled first? it doesn't seem to be working in my organization. i tried to send an email to myalias+tag@mydomain.com but i didn't receive anything at myalias@mydomain.com

Comment: @iSWORD  Haven't tried this in a while, so things might have changed. You shouldn't have to enable anything.